# Multiple versions with single database without duplicating code

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing payroll management with codeigniter. I will tell the design briefly.

I have single db. In that db, multiple clients are registered. Till now we provided single login form for clients by prompting username, password and client ID. But customer asking to give unique URL's for each and every client with out duplicating code and with single db.

For example: http://www.example.com/Client1, http://www.example.com/Client2 etc

So that client can enter username and password only. Based on the client code in url, we can validate username and password.

Just i want to know this is possible or not. Any problems will come in future?

Thanx

Comment: It is possible to  contains information of clientID in each URL. You shuld not use clientID itself in URL, because security with username and password is weeker then that with username, password and clientID.  You may be able to encripted clientID  which is encripted using username and password as keys.

Answer (score 0):

i got it
you can handle it from routes
in your routes file just call your database

```
$db =& DB();
$db->select('employe_name');
$query = $db->get( 'tbl_user' );
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
$route[ $row->name_prefered ]    =        ' http://www.example.com/dashboard';
```

now what acutely happens is when ever http://www.example.com/dashboard link hits it will change to http://www.example.com/employe name

Comment: Thanx for your reply Ahmed. If User clicks on  http://www.example.com/Client1 or  http://www.example.com/Client2 we need to display login screen first. So that we need to write as many as controllers and models and views based on client name right?

Comment: you can work on single one by getting it employee name from database make one controller and make it dynamic